# Jquery UI Datepicker not reloading after click out

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Have the following code... (in a bootstrap environment)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#DateValidfrom" ).datepicker( {
        showAnim: "clip",
        minDate: +2, 
        maxDate: "+24M +1D",
        dateFormat: "DD, d M yy",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        altField: "#alt-date",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function() {
            var date2 = $('#DateValidfrom').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+364)
            $( "#DateValidTo" ).datepicker("setDate", date2);
        }
    });
    $( "#DateValidTo" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
});
</script>
```

All works good - no probs UNTIL I click out of the datepicker field say to go to fill out a another field, come back to the datepicker field, click, and get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDate' of null(…)"

I refresh the page - all good again..

So, first click - works well, click out and come back again - no go - error as above.

This part of the code the problem?

```
       onClose: function() {
            var date2 = $('#DateValidfrom').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+364)
            $( "#DateValidTo" ).datepicker("setDate", date2);
        }
```

The 3 fields are

```
<input type="text" id="DateValidfrom" name="DateValidfrom" readonly class="form-control" required>
<input type="hidden" id="alt-date" name="DateValidfrom" />
<input name="DateValidTo" type="hidden" id="DateValidTo">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrrgghhhh....   Surely it can't be this simple???

Changed

```
onClose: function() {
```

To

```
onSelect: function() {
```

Seems to work?  Correct?